# Alternative to lookbehind with variable width

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I have some html which contains a number of hyperlinks to html files, but they don't have any file extensions.

For example in the string `<a href='variablelengthfilename'>` I'm trying to match the trailing `'` , so I can replace it with `.html'` (using a RegEx search in Notepad++) using something like this:

```
`(?<=href='[A-Za-z]*)'`
```

but that won't work because Notepad++ doesn't allow variable-length lookbehind assertions.

How else can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You do not need a look-behind, use `\bhref='[^']*` and replace with `$&.html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working in Notepad++, here is a way to achieve what you are after:

Find what: `\bhref='[^']*`

Replace with: `$&.html`

The `\bhref='[^']*` regex matches a `href` as a whole word, then `='` are matched literally, and `[^']*` matches 0 or more characters other than `'`. Note you will need to replace `'` with `"` if the `href` value is inside double quotes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your links look like that, why not just do a simple replace

```
'>
```

with

```
.html'>
```

?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear on that - the page markup also included lots of other html elements as well as the hyperlinks, so I couldn't do that or everything else would have been affected too. Thanks